# sql query with complex statement

Tags: mysql, sql

I had the following tables in my database

**table users**

```
  user_id       full_name 
    1            user1         
    2            user2
    3            user3
```

**table users_phone**

```
 user_id            phone 

    1          2222222222
    1          3333333333
    2          1111111111
    2          4444444444
    2          5555555555
    3          6666666666
    3          7777777777
```

create a SQL statement that add phone columns for every users, 
I would want my SELECT statement to return the following:

```
 user_id     full_name          phone1           phone2           phone3
    1          user1          2222222222       3333333333     
    2          user2          1111111111       4444444444        5555555555
    3          user3          6666666666       7777777777
```

I'm attempting to create a SQL statement that does the following but obviously failing at it.

Here's about as far as I've gotten trying to figure this out.

```
select * from 
(select phone1 from users_phone as P
,(select phone2 from users_phone)as P 
(select phone3 from users_phone)as P)from users as U
where U.user_id=P.user_id
```

I've been melting my brain trying to figure out how or if this is even possible to do in a query any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: what if you have more than 3 phone numbers? and do you have a column that specifies the ordering of which phone number goes into which column?

Comment: This is another pivot question. Look to see if your RDBMS supports the PIVOT command, also look into reporting tools more suited for output such as this.

Comment: WHICH DBMS?????

Comment: no it 's just 3 phone numbers

Comment: but some users they have 1 or 2

Comment: i can use MySQL

Comment: No matter which phone number goes into which column

Answer (score 0):

In SQl Server I would use with and row_number to do it:
Like that:

```
;with cte as (
    select u.userId,
    p.phone, row_number() over (partition by u.userId order by u.userId)  as rn
    from @tb1 u
    join @tb2 p on u.userId = p.userId )

 select u.Userid, u.name, 
    (select cte.phone from cte where cte.userId = u.UserId and cte.rn = 1) as phone1,
    (select cte.phone from cte where cte.userId = u.UserId and cte.rn = 2) as phone2,
    (select cte.phone from cte where cte.userId = u.UserId and cte.rn = 3) as phone3
    from @tb1 u
```

[Print script result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0aNbT.png)

Comment: Next time you should ask for RDBMS before posting the answer, right now OP said is using MySQL and your question become invalid :(

Comment: You can do this in MySQL 8.0.3 too, because it now supports CTE and window functions.

Comment: @BillKarwin When they release that ? Doesnt have pivot too?

Comment: [MySQL 8.0.3 released 2017-09-21](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/relnotes/mysql/8.0/en/). This is still "Release Candidate" but the GA release should be ready in a few months.

Comment: For what it's worth, the `PIVOT` is a non-standard feature supported by Microsoft SQL Server 2005 and Oracle 11g. PostgreSQL has CROSSTAB which is kind of similar.